# Checking a Python module version at runtime

Tags: python, module, version

Many third-party Python modules have an attribute which holds the version information for the module (usually something like `module.VERSION` or `module.__version__`), however some do not.

Particular examples of such modules are libxslt and libxml2.

I need to check that the correct version of these modules are being used at runtime. Is there a way to do this?

A potential solution wold be to read in the source at runtime, hash it, and then compare it to the hash of the known version, but that's nasty.

Is there a better solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check the versions of Python modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180543/how-do-i-check-the-versions-of-python-modules)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd stay away from hashing.  The version of libxslt being used might contain some type of patch that doesn't effect your use of it.

As an alternative, I'd like to suggest that you don't check at run time (don't know if that's a hard requirement or not).  For the python stuff I write that has external dependencies (3rd party libraries), I write a script that users can run to check their python install to see if the appropriate versions of modules are installed.

For the modules that don't have a defined 'version' attribute, you can inspect the interfaces it contains (classes and methods) and see if they match the interface they expect.  Then in the actual code that you're working on, assume that the 3rd party modules have the interface you expect.

Answer (score 270):

Use [pkg_resources](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html). Anything installed from PyPI at least should have a version number.

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution("blogofile").version
'0.7.1'
```

Comment: Also note that, package name must be that of PyPI entry. So something like "pkg_resources.get_distribution('MySQLdb').version" won't work but "pkg_resources.get_distribution('mysql-python').version" will.

Comment: If you are running with an absolute file name, `pkg_resources` might pick up a different version shadowing the one you are actually running because it has higher precedence on your `PYTHONPATH` or similar.

Comment: In case somebody wants to know how to make the `__version__` attribute: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17583443/562769

Comment: `pkg_resources` link is an Error 404

Comment: For automated processing, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11887762/974555)

Comment: This unfortunately has quite a lot of limitations. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56910431/7262247

Comment: [DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/main/NEWS.rst#changes-4).

Answer (score 32):

If you're on python `>=3.8` you can use a module from the built-in library for that. To check a package's version (in this example `lxml`) run:

```
>>> from importlib.metadata import version
>>> version('lxml')
'4.3.1'
```

This functionality has been ported to older versions of python (`<3.8`) as well, but you need to install a separate library first:

```
pip install importlib_metadata
```

and then to check a package's version (in this example `lxml`) run:

```
>>> from importlib_metadata import version
>>> version('lxml')
'4.3.1'
```

Keep in mind that this works only for packages installed from PyPI. Also, you must pass a package name as an argument to the `version` method, rather than a module name that this package provides (although they're usually the same).

Comment: _"Keep in mind that this works only for packages installed from PyPI."_ It works for anything, you just need to import the target module first: `import httplib2 version('httplib2') '0.20.4'`.

Answer (score 6):

Some ideas:

1. Try checking for functions that exist or don't exist in your needed versions.
2. If there are no function differences, inspect function arguments and signatures.
3. If you can't figure it out from function signatures, set up some stub calls at import time and check their behavior.

Comment: Packages should specify their version. These ideas are totally overkill for the usually (estimated 99% of the cases) easy task of checking a version.

Answer (score 3):

I found it quite unreliable to use the various tools available (including the best one `pkg_resources` mentioned by [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4939465/7262247)), as most of them do not cover all cases. For example

- built-in modules
- modules not installed but just added to the python path (by your IDE for example)
- two versions of the same module available (one in python path superseding the one installed)

Since we needed a reliable way to get the version of *any* package, module or submodule, I ended up writing [getversion](https://smarie.github.io/python-getversion/). It is quite simple to use:

```
from getversion import get_module_version
import foo
version, details = get_module_version(foo)
```

See the [documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-getversion/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
pip freeze
```

to see the installed packages in requirements format.

Answer (score 0):

For modules which do not provide `__version__` the following is ugly but works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import re

sp = subprocess.run(["pip3", "show", "numpy"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ver = sp.stdout.decode('utf-8').strip().split('\n')[1]
res = re.search('^Version:\ (.*)$', ver)
print(res.group(1))
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import re

sp = subprocess.run(["pip3", "show", "numpy"], capture_output=True)
ver = sp.stdout.decode('utf-8').strip().split('\n')[1]
res = re.search('^Version:\ (.*)$', ver)
print(res.group(1))
```