# How do I get a python module's version number through code?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the version number of a specific few modules that I use. Something that I can store in a variable.

Comment: Related: [Checking Python module version at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710609/checking-python-module-version-at-runtime)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Generalized answer from Matt's, do a `dir(YOURMODULE)` and look for `__version__`, `VERSION`, or `version`.  Most modules like `__version__` but I think `numpy` uses `version.version`

Comment: Just to note that `__version__` is the preferred standard for new code, as recommended by [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). See [Standard way to embed version into Python package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458550/standard-way-to-embed-version-into-python-package)

Comment: `print(YOURMODULE.__version__)`

Comment: How do I do this from REPL without actually doing an import?

Comment: It seems like it only works for packages that define `__version__`, no?

Answer (score 97):

Use [pkg_resources](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html)(part of setuptools). Anything installed from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) at least has a version number. No extra package/module is needed.

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution("simplegist").version
'0.3.2'
```

Comment: pkg_resources import is very slow, the recommended way since Python 3.8 is via `importlib.metadata.version` as outlined above

Answer (score 51):

Starting `Python 3.8`, [`importlib.metadata`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/importlib.metadata.html) can be used as a replacement for `pkg_resources` to extract the version of third-party packages installed via tools such as `pip`:

```
from importlib.metadata import version
version('wheel')
# '0.33.4'
```

Comment: It now is ```from importlib_metadata import version``` for me --- so underscore instead of dot.

Comment: @OnceUponATime I believe that's what you need when running python 3.7 or below, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54869712/169947

Answer (score 7):

I think it depends on the module. For example, Django has a VERSION variable that you can get from `django.VERSION`, sqlalchemy has a `__version__` variable that you can get from `sqlalchemy.__version__`.

Comment: django also has `django.get_version()`, which returns a string rather than a tuple. When in doubt, `dir(module)`.

Comment: Or you can use the `getmembers` function from the [inspect module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html).

Comment: The above works for mock too. No luck with .get_distribution("xxx").version()

Answer (score 1):

Some modules (e.g. azure) do not provide a `__version__` string.

If the package was installed with pip, the following should work.

```
# say we want to look for the version of the "azure" module
import pip
for m in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    if m.project_name == 'azure':
        print(m.version)
```

Comment: I'm getting `AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'get_installed_distributions'`. Same result in Jupyter 5.0.0 and VS Code 1.30.2 using pip version 18.1. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry: looks like they changed the internal APIs of pip. It was not a supported use, anyway. https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5154

Answer (score -1):

```
 import sys
 import matplotlib as plt
 import pandas as pd
 import sklearn as skl
 import seaborn as sns

 print(sys.version)
 print(plt.__version__)
 print(pd.__version__)
 print(skl.__version__)
 print(sns.__version__)
```

The above code shows versions of respective modules:
Sample O/P:

3.7.1rc1 (v3.7.1rc1:2064bcf6ce, Sep 26 2018, 14:21:39) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)]
3.1.0
0.24.2
0.21.2
0.9.0
(sys shows version of python )