How to get the pandas version in Python with numpy >= 2.0.0 installed
One usually gets the pandas version in Python as follows:
import pandas
print(pandas.__version__)

However if numpy version 2.0.0 or higher is installed, and the pandas version is < 2.2.2
it typically crashes as follows on the import statement:

Is there a clever way to check the pandas version (within Python) in order to warn the user of this incompatibility instead of the user-unfriendly traceback dump?

You could use a try: ... except ValueError: ... to catch the error pandas is throwing.

Okay, I can trap it that way but I would also like the pandas version number within the message.

You can get a package's version without importing it using importlib: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524168/how-do-i-get-a-python-modules-version-number-through-code

You can use try except block to catch the error and return. Sample code is as follows:
try:
    import pandas as pd
except ValueError as e:
    print(f"Import error: {e}")

