# How do I get the version of an installed module in Python programmatically?

Tags: python

For the modules:

```python
required_modules = ['nose', 'coverage', 'webunit', 'MySQLdb', 'pgdb', 'memcache']
```

and programs:

```python
required_programs = ['psql', 'mysql', 'gpsd', 'sox', 'memcached']
```

Something like:

```python
# Report on the versions of programs installed
for module in required_modules:
    try:
        print module.__version__
    except:
        exit
```

Comment: As I understand it, there's no simple, perfect way to do this. But [the answers to this prior question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710609/checking-python-module-version-at-runtime) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `module.__version__` isn't present in all modules.

A workaround is to use a package manager. When you install a library using *easy_install* or *pip*, it keeps a record of the installed version. Then you can do:

```
import pkg_resources
version = pkg_resources.get_distribution("nose").version
```

Comment: somehow MySQLdb is not working with .__version__
on a command line i can import and use MySQLdb.__version__
but when i use the same syntax in script it does not give me the version number

Answer (score -1):

I found it quite unreliable to use the various tools available (including the best one `pkg_resources` mentioned by [moraes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080232/7262247)), as most of them do not cover all cases.

Version numbers in python can be in very different places depending on the case:

- for modules and packages, on the optional `__version__` attribute as recommended by PEP396. It should be considered inherited by subpackages and submodules by default if they do not have the attribute.
- for distributed modules and packages, on the `Version` Metadata field as indicated by PEP345, that is located:

  - for built wheels distributions (PEP427), on the `dist-info` directory, but also in the dist-info folder name
  - for built eggs distributions (legacy format from setuptools), on the `egg-info` directory, but is also in the egg-info folder name
- finally, for built-in modules and packages, the default version should be inherited from the python system version except if overridden

In addition to this, at runtime (when you need that version number), packages and modules can be

- already imported or not
- built and pip-installed (in debug mode or not), or simply added to the PYTHON PATH (sys.path)
- non-built and added to the PYTHON PATH (sys.path)

This variety of settings makes it very difficult for existing solutions to tackle all aspects of this problem. `pkg_resources` is probably the best way to get it as of today, but does not work for example when a package is an unzipped wheel added to the PYTHON PATH. It also does not support built-in modules.

Since we needed a reliable way to get the version of *any* package, module or submodule, I ended up writing [getversion](https://smarie.github.io/python-getversion/). It implements a series of strategies in sequence, until something works.

It is quite simple to use:

```py
from getversion import get_module_version

# Get the version of an imported module
from xml import dom
version, details = get_module_version(dom)
```

In particular the `details` provide useful hints about how the version flag was retrieved:

```
> print(details)
Version '3.7.3.final.0' found for module 'xml.dom' by strategy 'get_builtin_module_version', after the following failed attempts:
 - Attempts for module 'xml.dom':
   - <get_module_version_attr>: module 'xml.dom' has no attribute '__version__'
 - Attempts for module 'xml':
   - <get_module_version_attr>: module 'xml' has no attribute '__version__'
   - <get_version_using_pkgresources>: Invalid version number: None
   - <get_builtin_module_version>: SUCCESS: 3.7.3.final.0
```

See the [documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-getversion/) for details. I copied the above details about the problem from [this page](https://smarie.github.io/python-getversion/#why-another-package).

Comment: Could the downvoter explain why this vote ? Indeed if you read documentation of `getversion` you will find that the accepted answer above is not reliable : `pkg_resources` sometimes does not provide the required answer (for example consider updated python path due to IDE project-to-project dependency setup)

Comment: I ended up editing the post hoping that it is clearer.