# How do I check the versions of Python modules?

Tags: python

I installed the Python modules `construct` and `statlib` using `setuptools`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools

sudo easy_install statlib
sudo easy_install construct
```

How do I check their versions from the command line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking python module version at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710609/checking-python-module-version-at-runtime)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524168/how-do-i-get-a-python-modules-version-number-through-code

Comment: For those interested by a command line solution, use: `pip list`

Answer (score 1093, accepted):

[Use `pip` instead of `easy_install`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3220572/1265154)

With pip, list all installed packages and their versions via:

```
pip freeze
```

On most Linux systems, you can pipe this to `grep` (or `findstr` on Windows) to find the row for the particular package you're interested in.

---

#### Linux:

```
pip freeze | grep lxml
```

> lxml==2.3

#### Windows:

```
pip freeze | findstr lxml
```

> lxml==2.3

---

For an individual module, you can try the [`__version__` attribute](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/). However, there are modules without it:

```
python -c "import requests; print(requests.__version__)"
2.14.2

python -c "import lxml; print(lxml.__version__)"
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): 
> File "<string>", line 1, in <module> 
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '**version**'

Lastly, as the commands in your question are prefixed with `sudo`, it appears you're installing to the global python environment. I strongly advise to take look into Python [virtual environment](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) managers, for example [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: an answer below suggested `pip show lxml | grep Version` ; this will run much faster, since it only inspects a single package.

Comment: Just for completeness: A third version is `pip list | grep lxml`

Comment: How about on Windows system? What is the `grep` in windows? Since pip freeze | grep lxml doesn't work on windwos.

Comment: @RavenCheuk use `pip list | findstr lxml`

Comment: windows variant with find (1 character shorter...): pip list | find "lxml"

Comment: ```pip freeze | grep keras``` did not show the version of installed keras, but ```pip show keras | grep Version``` did show. That means ```pip freeze | grep library name``` cannot be used for all libraries.

Comment: I seem to be getting a discrepancy in output: >>print(sklearn.__version__)   #returns 0.20.3  >>pip show sklearn   #return 0.0; can you clarify?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not cover many cases :( . Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56912343/7262247 . It includes the method that you suggest ('pip' package info and  module `__version__` ) but also covers many more

Comment: `'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: This isn't working when the version is defined in a setuptools.setup function, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 514):

You can try

```
>>> import statlib
>>> print statlib.__version__

>>> import construct
>>> print contruct.__version__
```

This is the approach recommended by [PEP 396](https://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396). But that PEP was never accepted and has been deferred. In fact, there appears to be increasing support amongst Python core developers to recommend *not* including a `__version__` attribute, e.g. in *[Remove importlib_metadata.**version**.](https://gitlab.com/python-devs/importlib_metadata/-/merge_requests/125)*.

Comment: Some versions of some common libraries (such as `inspect`) not not have a `__version__` attribute, unfortunately.

Comment: PySerial has `serial.VERSION`. Maybe there are some other commonly used modules as well, which aren't following PEP 0396:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/

Comment: a lot of modules do not have __version__

Comment: @sdaffa23fdsf which modules do not have version?  More than serial, inspect, PyQt and SQLite?  See [pycmake](https://github.com/Statoil/pycmake/blob/master/pycmake.cmake).

Comment: +1 because this works on any OS. Even if some modules do not have a __version__ attribute, this is by far the easiest.

Comment: I get > " module has no attribute version" with serial.VERSION on Python 2.7 !

Comment: `print(contruct.__version__)` if using Python 3.*

Comment: I seem to be getting a discrepancy in output: >>print(sklearn.__version__)   #returns 0.20.3  >>pip show sklearn   #return 0.0; can you clarify?

Comment: Beware that PEP 396 was never accepted and has been deferred: python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396

Comment: You don't even need the `print` part, as this example shows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59631210/4561887. Just `import yaml` and then `yaml.__version__` is enough, for instance, in a live Python interactive session.

Comment: Re *"contruct"*: Not *"construct"*? (with an "s"). In any case, it makes it easier to see [who has plagiarised your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180543/how-to-check-the-version-of-python-modules/59631210#59631210)!

Answer (score 445):

**Python >= 3.8:**

If you're on Python >= 3.8, you can use a module from the built-in library for that. To check a package's version (in this example `construct`) run:

```
>>> from importlib.metadata import version
>>> version('construct')
'4.3.1'
```

**Python < 3.8:**

Use [`pkg_resources`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#getting-or-creating-distributions) module distributed with [`setuptools`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library. Note that the string that you pass to `get_distribution` method should correspond to the PyPI entry.

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution('construct').version
'2.5.2'
```

**Side notes:**

1. Note that the string that you pass to the `get_distribution` method should be the package **name as registered in PyPI**, not the module name that you are trying to import. Unfortunately, these aren't always the same (e.g. you do `pip install memcached`, but `import memcache`).
2. If you want to apply this solution from the command line you can do something like:

```
python -c \
  "import pkg_resources; print(pkg_resources.get_distribution('construct').version)"
```

Comment: This works even if the module does not have the attribute `__version__`.

Comment: What about this? ``construct.version.full_version``

Comment: Should be the top answer, it's the only reliable way of getting the package version (if there is one)

Comment: Looks like this plays nicely with the version you specify in setuptools's `setup` call. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `pkg_resources.get_distrinbution` does not always work either.  It issues some `DistributionNotFound` exception with error message like : "The 'the_package_name' distribution was not found and is required by the application"

Comment: So far this is the best solution working with **pbr** packager. Thank you!

Comment: @mjv your error  most likely occurs because 1) the package is not installed 2) you're passing a module name instead of a package name to the `get_distribution` method

Comment: For Python < 3.8 I think you should recommend `importlib_metadata` over `pkg_resources`, it will be more consistent with how stdlib `importlib.metadata` works.

Comment: @wim thanks for the suggestion, I also thought about it. I decided to stick with `pkg_resources` for now, because you're more likely to have it already installed (via `setuptools`). `importlib_metadata` needs to be installed separately, so I think there's a bit more friction.

Comment: Importing packages can be costly, just reading package meta information therefore can be beneficial.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Works across different OSes and doesn't require importing the packages, just to see their versions.

Comment: @wim I'm trying both and it seems that if you have installed several versions of one project and not purge everything `importlib_metadata` is **not reliable**, since it will get the first of the `distributions` it finds instead of the one being used. I find that `pkg_resources` is showing the "at use" version.

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz How are you installing multiple versions of the same package in the first place, these days?  `pip` won't do it, and [`easy_install`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/easy_install.html) along with it's multi-installs has been deprecated since 2019..

Comment: @wim sorry, I may have lead to a misunderstanding! What I mean is, you work on a project, you keep updating over time its deps but without uninstalling previous version, the whole of the dist infos are kept in the `site-packages` right? So `distributions` is going to get one of those, but not specifically the one that is currently in use, so that's not a reliable way to get it

Comment: No, those dist-info dirs would not be left around in site-packages, generally.  They should be removed when you install updated version, because pip will uninstall the old package before installing a different version.

Comment: this is not working in python 3.9.2

Answer (score 178):

Use `pip show` to find the version!

```
# In order to get the package version, execute the below command
pip show YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME | grep Version
```

---

You can use `pip show YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME` - which gives you all details of package. This also works in Windows.

`grep Version` is used in Linux to filter out the version and show it.

Comment: No joy here!
`pip: error: No command by the name pip show
  (maybe you meant "pip install show")`

Comment: This answer is only really suitable if you need a package version from the shell. If you need it within Python, this would be a pretty bad hack. Anyways, you can use the following command to extract the version: `pip show PACKAGE | awk '/^Version: / {sub("^Version: ", ""); print}'`. You could probably get away with a simpler AWK script, but the aforementioned will be safer for any edge cases.

Comment: @SamFinnigan `pip show` was implemented in *pip 1.2.1.post1*. You are using a terribly dated version of pip so no wonder you're having trouble! I'm currently running *pip 7.1.2*. If something is preventing you from updating, you can always just install it locally or in a virtualenv.

Comment: has worked for me thanks. some of the packeges have not .__version__ parameter so that one is more useful.

Comment: I seem to be getting a discrepancy in output: >>print(sklearn.__version__)   #returns 0.20.3  >>pip show sklearn   #return 0.0; can you clarify?

Comment: `'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: This appears to install a totally unrelated package [show](https://pypi.org/project/show/) (as root!). That command is not "in order to run `pip show`", pip has had a show subcommand for as long as I remember. How did this get 100 upvotes!?

Comment: you can actually use `pip show YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME` to get all the details of the package. Works in Windows. `grep Version` is to get the version only and ignore other details.

Comment: On some systems, it may be `pip3 show` instead of `pip show`.

Comment: @Black Thunder: On what system (incl. versions)?

Comment: Using `pip show` is not the most reliable way because people often get confused by multiple installations of python, pip, virtual envs, etc. For real debugging, you need to check the version inside python code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180543/how-do-i-check-the-versions-of-python-modules/32965521#32965521

Answer (score 121):

The *better* way to do that is:

---

**For the details of a specific package**

```
pip show <package_name>
```

It details out the package_name, version, author, location, etc.

---

```
$ pip show numpy

Name: numpy
Version: 1.13.3
Summary: NumPy: array processing for numbers, strings, records, and objects.
Home-page: http://www.numpy.org
Author: NumPy Developers
Author-email: numpy-discussion@python.org
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\prowinjvm\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
Requires:
```

---

**For more details:** `>>> pip help`

---

`pip` should be updated to do this.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

On Windows the recommended command is:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: I seem to be getting a discrepancy in output: >>print(sklearn.__version__)   #returns 0.20.3  >>pip show sklearn   #return 0.0; can you clarify?

Comment: You should use `pip show scikit-learn` instead of `pip show sklearn`. sklearn is short form used during import, not recognize directly in `pip` since `scikit-learn` is the full package learn not `sklearn`

Comment: Using `pip show` is not the most reliable way because people often get confused by multiple installations of python, pip, virtual envs, etc. For real debugging, you need to check the version inside python code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180543/how-do-i-check-the-versions-of-python-modules/32965521#32965521

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/23324265/270302

Answer (score 55):

In Python 3 with brackets around print:

```
>>> import celery
>>> print(celery.__version__)
3.1.14
```

Comment: Not every package has a `__version__` attribute.

Comment: @user1976 This is valid syntax in Python 2 as well.  The parentheses are simply tolerated around the argument to `print`, just like `(2)+(3)` evaluates to `5`.  When you have a comma inside the parentheses, things may get marginally more interesting, though for `print`, it still works, sort of.

Comment: This answer does not contribute any new insights compared to older answers.

Answer (score 30):

In the Python 3.8 version, there is a new [`metadata`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#new-modules) module in the `importlib` package, which can do that as well.

Here is an example from the documentation:

```py
>>> from importlib.metadata import version
>>> version('requests')
'2.22.0'
```

Comment: This method has the benefit to work when __version__ attribute isn't defined.

Comment: except when it doesn't  `version('email')`

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'lower'` ...

Comment: @SanjayManohar Just tested using `python3.10.6` and `pandas1.5.2`. Works as expected.

Answer (score 27):

`module.__version__` is a good first thing to try, but it doesn't always work.

If you don't want to shell out, and you're using pip 8 or 9, you can still use `pip.get_installed_distributions()` to get versions from within Python:

*The solution here works in pip 8 and 9, but in pip 10 the function has been moved from `pip.get_installed_distributions` to `pip._internal.utils.misc.get_installed_distributions` to explicitly indicate that it's not for external use. It's not a good idea to rely on it if you're using pip 10+.*

```python
import pip

pip.get_installed_distributions()  # -> [distribute 0.6.16 (...), ...]

[
    pkg.key + ': ' + pkg.version
    for pkg in pip.get_installed_distributions()
    if pkg.key in ['setuptools', 'statlib', 'construct']
] # -> nicely filtered list of ['setuptools: 3.3', ...]
```

Comment: Yes, not all package creators set __version__, but if you're using `pip`, this should always work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution isn't viable. Pip doesn't guarantee any in-process API, only an API through the command-line. This approach no longer works on pip 10.

Answer (score 20):

The previous answers did not solve my problem, but this code did:

```
import sys 
for name, module in sorted(sys.modules.items()): 
  if hasattr(module, '__version__'): 
    print name, module.__version__
```

Comment: This just avoids attempting to print `__version__` if it not defined.  If there is no `__version__`, you receive no result for the package you want.

Comment: If the module does no have a `__version__` attribute, which is the standard (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/#specification), it is impossible to know where and how the version is included without manual investigation.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29770964/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 15):

Use **`dir()`** to find out if the module has a **`__version__`** attribute at all.

```
>>> import selenium
>>> dir(selenium)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__',
 '__package__', '__path__', '__version__']
>>> selenium.__version__
'3.141.0'
>>> selenium.__path__
['/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium']
```

Comment: Exactly I looked for Selenium version - and magically here we have it! Works with Python3 so - good job!

Comment: And what to do if there's no `__version__`?

Answer (score 13):

You can try this:

```
pip list
```

This will output all the packages with their versions.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gF8J.png)

Comment: To see packages installed through "pip3",  "pip3 list" has to be used

Answer (score 10):

Some modules don't have `__version__` attribute, so the easiest way is check in the terminal: `pip list`

Comment: To see packages installed through "pip3", "pip3 list" has to be used

Answer (score 8):

If the methods in previous answers do not work, it is worth trying the following in Python:

```
import modulename

modulename.version
modulename.version_info
```

See *[Get the Python Tornado version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146153/get-python-tornado-version/31146188)*

Note, the `.version` worked for me on a few others, besides [Tornado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tornado_(web_server)) as well.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming we are using [Jupyter Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter) (if using Terminal, drop the exclamation marks):

1. if the package (e.g., xgboost) was installed with **pip**:

   ```
   !pip show xgboost
   !pip freeze | grep xgboost
   !pip list | grep xgboost
   ```
2. if the package (e.g. *caffe*) was installed with [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)):

   ```
   !conda list caffe
   ```

Answer (score 7):

This answer is for Windows users. As suggested in all other answers, you can use the statements as:

```
import [type the module name]
print(module.__version__) # module + '.' + double underscore + version + double underscore
```

But, there are some modules which don't print their version even after using the method above. So, you can simply do:

1. Open the command prompt.
2. Navigate to the file address/directory by using **cd** (**file address**) where you've kept your Python and all supporting modules installed. If you have only one Python interpreter on your system, the [PyPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Package_Index) packages are normally visible in the directory/folder: *Python* → *Lib* → *site-packages*.
3. use the command "**pip install [module name]**" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. This will show you a message as "**Requirement already satisfied: file address\folder name (with version)**".
5. See the screenshot below for example: I had to know the version of a pre-installed module named "Selenium-Screenshot". It correctly showed as 1.5.0:

[image: Command prompt screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

Go to terminal like pycharm-terminal

Now write `py` or `python`
and hit **Enter**.

Now you are inside python in the terminal you can try this way:

```
# import <name_of_the_library>

import kivy

# So if the library has __version__ magic method, so this way will help you

kivy.__version__  # then hit Enter to see the version

# Output >> '2.1.0'
```

but if the above way not working for you can try this way to know information include the version of the library

```
 pip show module <HERE PUT THE NAME OF THE LIBRARY>
```

Example:

```
pip show module pyperclip

Output:
       Name: pyperclip
       Version: 1.8.2
       Summary: A cross-platform clipboard module for Python. (Only handles plain text for now.)
       Home-page: https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip
       Author: Al Sweigart
       Author-email: al@inventwithpython.com
       License: BSD
       Location: c:\c\kivymd\virt\lib\site-packages
       Requires:
       Required-by:
```

There is another way that could help you to show all the libraries and versions of them inside the project:

```
pip freeze
# I used the above command in a terminal inside my project this is the output
       certifi==2021.10.8
       charset-normalizer==2.0.12
       docutils==0.18.1
       idna==3.3
       Kivy==2.1.0
       kivy-deps.angle==0.3.2
       kivy-deps.glew==0.3.1
       kivy-deps.sdl2==0.4.5
       Kivy-Garden==0.1.5
       kivymd @ file:///C:/c/kivymd/KivyMD
       Pillow==9.1.0
       Pygments==2.12.0
       pyperclip==1.8.2
       pypiwin32==223
       pywin32==303
       requests==2.27.1
       urllib3==1.26.9
```

and sure you can try using the below command to show all libraries and their versions

```
pip list
```

Hope to Help anyone,
Greetings

Answer (score 6):

I suggest opening a Python shell in the terminal (in the Python version you are interested), importing the library, and getting its `__version__` attribute.

```
>>> import statlib
>>> statlib.__version__

>>> import construct
>>> contruct.__version__
```

**Note 1:** We must regard the **Python version**. If we have installed different versions of Python, we have to open the terminal in the Python version we are interested in. For example, opening the terminal with Python 3.8 can (surely will) give a different version of a library than opening with Python 3.5 or Python 2.7.

**Note 2:** We **avoid using the `print` function**, because its behavior depends on Python 2 or Python 3. We do not need it, and the terminal will show the value of the expression.

Answer (score 5):

First add executables `python` and `pip` to your environment variables. So that you can execute your commands from command prompt. Then simply give Python command.

Then import the package:

```
import scrapy
```

Then print the version name

```
print(scrapy.__version__)
```

This will definitely work.

Comment: as several times discussed here, not every module provides an `__version__` attribute.

Comment: I found a package that does not show with `pip freeze` however <package>.__version_ worked. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 5):

In summary:

```
conda list
```

(It will provide all the libraries along with version details.)

And:

```
pip show tensorflow
```

(It gives complete library details.)

Comment: Using `conda list`, you can name the package you want, for example `conda list statlib`.

Answer (score 4):

This works in [Jupyter Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter) on Windows, too! As long as Jupyter is launched from a Bash-compliant command line such as [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) ([Mingw-w64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mingw-w64)), the solutions given in many of the answers can be used in Jupyter Notebook on Windows systems with one tiny tweak.

I'm running Windows 10 Pro with Python installed via [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)), and the following code works when I launch Jupyter via Git Bash (but does not when I launch from the Anaconda prompt).

The tweak: Add an exclamation mark (`!`) in front of `pip` to make it `!pip`.

```
>>>!pip show lxml | grep Version
Version: 4.1.0

>>>!pip freeze | grep lxml
lxml==4.1.0

>>>!pip list | grep lxml
lxml                               4.1.0

>>>!pip show lxml
Name: lxml
Version: 4.1.0
Summary: Powerful and Pythonic XML processing library combining libxml2/libxslt with the ElementTree API.
Home-page: http://lxml.de/
Author: lxml dev team
Author-email: lxml-dev@lxml.de
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\karls\anaconda2\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: jupyter-contrib-nbextensions
```

Answer (score 4):

After scouring the Internet, trying to figure out how to ensure the version of a module I’m running (apparently `python_is_horrible.__version__` isn’t a thing in Python 2?) across operating systems and Python versions... literally none of these answers worked for my scenario...

Then I thought about it a minute and realized the basics... after ~30 minutes of fails...

> assumes the module *is already* installed and can be imported

---

### Python 3.7

```
>>> import sys,sqlite3
>>> sys.modules.get("sqlite3").version
'2.6.0'
>>> ".".join(str(x) for x in sys.version_info[:3])
'3.7.2'
```

---

### Python 2.7

```
>>> import sys,sqlite3
>>> sys.modules.get("sqlite3").version
'2.6.0'
>>> ".".join(str(x) for x in sys.version_info[:3])
'2.7.11'
```

Literally that’s it...

Comment: note: not all packages have a `.version` attribute `sys.modules.get("numpy").version`

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax for the life of me I can't understand why there isn't more uniformity with both this, and the import model for python modules/packages. Constant headache

Answer (score 2):

A Python program to list all packages (you can copy it to file *requirements.txt*):

```
from pip._internal.utils.misc import get_installed_distributions
print_log = ''
for module in sorted(get_installed_distributions(), key=lambda x: x.key):
    print_log +=  module.key + '~=' + module.version  + '\n'
print(print_log)
```

The output would look like:

```
asn1crypto~=0.24.0
attrs~=18.2.0
automat~=0.7.0
beautifulsoup4~=4.7.1
botocore~=1.12.98
```

Answer (score 2):

(See also *[How do I get the version of an installed module in Python programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079735/how-do-i-get-the-version-of-an-installed-module-in-python-programatically/56912280#56912280)*)

I found it quite unreliable to use the various tools available (including the best one `pkg_resources` mentioned by [Jakub Kukul' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32965521/7262247)), as **most of them do not cover all cases**. For example

- built-in modules
- modules not installed but just added to the python path (by your IDE for example)
- two versions of the same module available (one in python path superseding the one installed)

Since we needed a reliable way to get the version of *any* package, module or submodule, I ended up writing [getversion](https://smarie.github.io/python-getversion/). It is quite simple to use:

```
from getversion import get_module_version
import foo
version, details = get_module_version(foo)
```

See [the documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-getversion/) for details.

Answer (score 2):

For situations where field `__version__` is not defined:

```py
try:
    from importlib import metadata
except ImportError:
    import importlib_metadata as metadata # python<=3.7

metadata.version("package")
```

Alternatively, and like it was already mentioned:

```py
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.get_distribution('package').version
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of non-standard (pip) modules imported in the current module:

```
[{pkg.key : pkg.version} for pkg in pip.get_installed_distributions() 
   if pkg.key in set(sys.modules) & set(globals())]
```

Result:

```
>>> import sys, pip, nltk, bs4
>>> [{pkg.key : pkg.version} for pkg in pip.get_installed_distributions() if pkg.key in set(sys.modules) & set(globals())]
[{'pip': '9.0.1'}, {'nltk': '3.2.1'}, {'bs4': '0.0.1'}]
```

Note:

This code was put together from solutions both on this page and from [How to list imported modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858100/how-to-list-imported-modules)

Answer (score 1):

I myself work in a heavily restricted server environment and unfortunately none of the solutions here are working for me. There may be no global solution that fits all, but I figured out a swift workaround by reading the terminal output of pip freeze within my script and storing the modules labels and versions in a dictionary.

```
import os
os.system('pip freeze > tmpoutput')
with open('tmpoutput', 'r') as f:
    modules_version = f.read()
  
module_dict = {item.split("==")[0]:item.split("==")[-1] for item in modules_versions.split("\n")}
```

Retrieve your module's versions through passing the module label key, e.g.:

```
>>  module_dict["seaborn"]
'0.9.0'
```

Comment: What is a *"no glove solution"*? Do you mean *"no global solution"*? Or something else? Is it an idiom?

Comment: yea, global.. edited. thanks

Answer (score 1):

And in case your production system is hardened beyond comprehension so it has neither `pip` nor `conda`, here is a Bash replacement for `pip freeze`:

```
ls /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages | grep info | awk -F "-" '{print $1"=="$2}' | sed 's/.dist//g'
```

*(make sure you update your `dist-packages` folder to your current python version and ignore inconsistent names, e.g., underscores vs. dashes).*

Sample printout:

```
Flask==1.1.2
Flask_Caching==1.10.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
[..]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small Bash program to get the version of any package in your Python environment. Just copy this to your `/usr/bin` and provide it with executable permissions:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
packageName=$1

python -c "import ${packageName} as package; print(package.__version__)"
```

Then you can just run it in the terminal, assuming you named the script `py-check-version`:

```
py-check-version whatever_package
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check what is alaready installed version of any packages you can simply use Pip command as below

**Template**

```
pip show <PACKAGE_NAME> | grep Version or pip show <PACKAGE_NAME>
```

**with pip3**

```
 pip3 show <PACKAGE_NAME> | grep Version or pip3 show <PACKAGE_NAME>
```

**Example**

```
pip show PyYAML | grep Version
Version: 3.12



pip3 show PyYAML | grep Version
Version: 3.12
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Jakub Kukul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32965521/7262247) I found a more reliable way to solve this problem.

The main problem of that approach is that requires the packages to be installed "conventionally" (and that does not include using `pip install --user`), or be in the system PATH at Python initialisation.

To get around that you can use `pkg_resources.find_distributions(path_to_search)`. This basically searches for distributions that would be importable if `path_to_search` was in the system PATH.

We can iterate through this generator like this:

```python
avail_modules = {}
distros = pkg_resources.find_distributions(path_to_search)
for d in distros:
    avail_modules[d.key] = d.version
```

This will return a dictionary having modules as keys and their version as value. This approach can be extended to a lot more than version number.

Thanks to Jakub Kukul for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use `subprocess.getoutput(python3 --version)`:

```
import subprocess as sp
print(sp.getoutput(python3 --version))

# Or however it suits your needs!
py3_version = sp.getoutput(python3 --version)

def check_version(name, version):...

check_version('python3', py3_version)
```

For more information and ways to do this without depending on the `__version__` attribute:

*[Assign output of os.system to a variable and prevent it from being displayed on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on)*

You can also use `subprocess.check_output()` which raises an error when the subprocess returns anything other than exit code 0:

*[subprocess — Subprocess management](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#check_output())*

Comment: This is the python version itself, the question is asking about package versions.

Answer (score -2):

You can first install some package like this and then check its version:

```
pip install package
import package
print(package.__version__)
```

It should give you the package version.

Comment: `__version__` attribute is already mentioned in many other answers here, what new information is this answer contributing?