# Django South Guardian

Tags: python, django, django-south, django-guardian

I was trying to update the db using South.  Created the new classes in models.py, usual stuff.

Working with WinXP, Django 1.6.8, south 0.8.4, django-guardian 1.3.0.dev, virtual-env 1.10.1

Using the usual `python manage.py schemamigration app_name --auto` found the new tables as expected.

Next used `python manage.py migrate app_name`but this failed reporting

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "guardian_userobjectpermission" does not exist
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "guardian_userobjectpermission" WHERE "guardian_...
```

I read [How to check version of python modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180543/how-to-check-version-of-python-modules)  but did not find the answer.

Tommy.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is open command prompt and `Run As`.  In requester window enter the credentials user: postgres and psw: postgres.  This opens a CMD window with admin rights to the db.  django-guardian does not now quarrel and the tables are created as expected.

Use `python manage.py migrate app_name --fake` first. Then run python `manage.py migrate app_name`

Hope this helps someone.

Tommy