# Get the Python Tornado version

Tags: python, version, tornado

How do I get the current version of my Python Tornado module version?

With other packages I can do the following:

```
print <modulename>.__version__
```

Source:
*[How to check version of Python modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180543/how-to-check-version-of-python-modules)*

Comment: Have you tried using `dir` to see if there are any attributes that might be it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tornado has both `tornado.version`, which is a string for human consumption (currently "4.2"), and `tornado.version_info`, which is a numeric tuple that is better for programmatic comparisons (currently `(4, 2, 0, 0)`). The fourth value of `version_info` will be negative for betas and other pre-releases.

Comment: Is this specific to python tornado -> or should we be trying these properties on other packages which don't have    .__version__ ??

Comment: There's no standard about this, so it's worth a try on other packages. `version` and `version_info` are the names used in the `sys` module, and I know that `pycurl` uses the same names (although in pycurl `version_info` is a function instead of an attribute)

Answer (score 3):

If using [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), open a terminal and type `python`. Then `import tornado` and the write command `tornado.version`.

You will get output like `'4.2.1'`.

Answer (score 2):

With no reference, or reason I tried the following:

```
print tornado.version
```

which seems to do the trick.