# Using waf, how to check for a minimum version of a python module during configure?

Tags: python, build, waf

In addition to check for presence of a particular python module during `./waf configure`, I need to also check for it to be of minimum version number.

This is what I'm already doing in my `wscript`:

```
def configure(cfg):
    cfg.load('python')
    cfg.check_python_module('some_module')
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: > [For an individual module, you can try `__version__` attribute, however there are modules without it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20180597/2851815)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this https://waf.io/apidocs/tools/python.html#waflib.Tools.python.check_python_module

```py
def options(opt):
    opt.load('python')

def configure(conf):
    conf.load('python')
    conf.check_python_module(
        're',
        condition="ver > num(2, 0, 4) and ver <= num(3, 0, 0)")
```