# How to see the pysnmp version in Linux terminal without using pip

Tags: python, linux, pysnmp

I have installed the pysnmp module in Linux.

I want to know which version of the pysnmp is got installed. How can I see the pysnmp version through the Linux terminal..? `pysnmp -V` did not work.

I haven't pip installed in my linux, so `pip show pysnmp` is also not working..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check version of python modules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180543/how-to-check-version-of-python-modules)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also check a module's version from inside a Python interpreter:

```
>>> import pysnmp
>>> pysnmp.__version__
'4.3.2'
```

To do this from a shell, just execute it through `python -c`.

```
$ python -c "import pysnmp; print(pysnmp.__version__)"
'4.3.2'
```

This executes a string upon starting the Python interpreter from the shell, allowing you to easily run short commands without writing a new script file or loading an interactive intepreter.

Answer (score 1):

You can try that

```
pip show pysnmp
```

Or any version you want actually

```
pip show YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME | grep Version
```

Comment: I don't have pip installed in my linux. so it doesn't recognize the pip command..

Comment: Hi @SabinChacko, that's an interesting one. How do you install your version then?

Comment: I installed the library manually.. downloading the zip from sourceforge.net, extracting and at last executing python `setup.py install` .. I knew the version since I installed it manually but I needed to display it..

Comment: omg @SabinChacko the olds ways ... :) Have a try with pip for your next install. It is time and energy saving.

Comment: Yea.. I don't know.. sometimes we need to get things done at any cost.. :p And the most weird fact is that I'm installing this for a php program.. :p