# Finding a python module version gives error on production box but not my dev machine

Tags: python, django, pgdb

I have the pgdb module installed on my MacOsX development box, my code works (specifically a line that is pgdb.connect(etc..)  works great.  I runt his code on my main server (linux) and it it says module has no attribute connect.

I think it is a version issue so I do what is suggested here to view the versions:

[How to check version of python modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180543/how-to-check-version-of-python-modules)

That is I do:

```
python
import pgdb
print pgdb.__version__
```

On my macosX box, returns the version just fine on my development machine it gives the error again:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_version_'
```

Strange thing is, doing an import pgdb does not throw an error but it acts like it is not installed on my production box.  Perhaps it is a library mangling on the box I am not aware of?  I should say import pgdb as myspecialsomething (That didn't do it still says no connect) ?

The other thing is, I did do a sanity check and did a sudo pip install pgdb on the production box and got this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pgdb in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2>=2.5.2 in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from pgdb)

Also, now this isn't an issue of the name clashing like one poster thought might be a duplicate of.   Something else is going on, though interestingly enough when I check the file my os x is using and the file my centos is using for pgdb I get two different answers: (paths wouldn't surprise me but files themselves does)

MacOS X:

```
 >>> pgdb.__file__
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgdb.pyc'
```

CentOS:

```
 >>> pgdb.__file__
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgdb/__init__.pyc'
```

No idea for the difference.

Comment: I would go to the package and see if the folders are populated, your setup sounds very broken.

Comment: Guessing on the deployed side not the mac side, I would agree...I am not the sole manager of this box.  Here is the results of the ls on this location:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgdb
has the files __init__.py  __init__.pyc  pgdb.py  pgdb.pyc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Comment: I looked at this, unless I am misunderstanding what the link is saying my code I am running is some_test.py which certainly is not pgdb.py. Though I do suspect multiple versions/installed somehow.  I tried this with various modules all are broke.  Even an import math with print math.__version__ gives same errors :/

Answer (score 0):

You likely have file `pgdb.py` in your current working directory, i.e. the directory you start Python from. Remove or rename it and try again.

You can find out where module is located with:

```
print pgdb.__file__
```

or:

```
import os

print os.path.abspath(pgdb.__file__)
```

Comment: What do you mean by current directory, as stated above there is a folder under some others named site-packages and pgdb is a folder in there with init.py, init.pyc and pgdb.py and pgdy.pyc?

Comment: I mean the directory you start your script from.

Comment: Folder I start script from does not have a pgdb.py.  I wonder if there are somehow multiple installs of this or if I can just do a pip uninstall/remove somehow and try again from scratch on installing the pgdb ?

Comment: Okay I did that os print and got this:  /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgdb/__init__.pyc
   Not sure if this is relevant but I was testing with gdal (which I know exsists on the server as well)  if I do a import gdal and then a print gdal.__version__ I get that module error.  If I do a from osgeo import gdal and then do that, then the print gdal.__version__ works fine.  I think I have to do a from on the pgdb too?  maybe?

Comment: also just did this:  >>> from pgdb import connect
 and it fails

Comment: Also looking at my mac the file points to there:  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgdb.pyc
   it is like it is pointing to the wrong file?  Or perhaps the OS difference requires mac os to use pgdb.pyc not __init__.pyc?

Comment: I broke out my windows machine with python 2.7x on it.  I did a pip install pgdb on it and then checked the file path, same as the centos points to the __init__.pyc and has the same issue doing a print pgdb.__version__  :(  So tells me I am doing something wrong and might be a simple fix but no idea what that could be.