# Finding the Specific Version of Python's Math and CMath Modules

Tags: python, version-control

This question should be relatively quick and easy. I just am trying to find out which version of Python's `math` and `cmath` packages I have.

Unfortunately, I did not install them using `pip`. I have already reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180543/how-to-check-version-of-python-modules) stack article which was helpful (because I did not know `pip freeze` before). However, both packages are not on the list.

I've tried google and looking around a bit, but to no avail. I have tried the following in the interpreter:

```
import math
print math.__version # error
print math.version # error
```

I have also tried to use python's `help` command and breeze through the documentation, but once again, couldn't find anything about how to detect which version I have installed.

I'm not exactly sure what else to try. Any thoughts? Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Neither `math` or `cmath` carry any specific version. They're related to the Python version you're using.

---

If it's because you want to check whether a function is present or not, let's say `isfinite` which was added in 3.2. Then you could do that using `hasattr`:

```
print(hasattr(math, "isfinite"))
```

or using `sys.version_info`:

```
has_infinite = sys.version_info >= (3, 2)
print(has_infinite)
```

*Both prints `True` since I'm using Python 3.6.*

Comment: That is fantastic! Where did you learn or read that?! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely agree with @Vallentin

If you want to know available attribute or methods you could use `dir()` function.
`dir()` is a powerful inbuilt function in Python 3, which returns list of the attributes and methods of any object (say functions , modules, strings, lists, dictionaries etc.)

```
import math
print(dir(math))
```

It will returns a list of available attributes and methods from `math` packages.