# How do I find the version for datetime, math, win32com.client?

Tags: python, datetime, win32com

I tried the below code in Anaconda Prompt

```
import <module name>
print(<module name>.__version__)
print(<module name>.version.VERSION)
print(<module name>.version)
```

but get **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'version'** for each print.

Is it be'cos datetime, math, win32com.client are in-built library in Python? So how do I find their version?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the Specific Version of Python's Math and CMath Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866483/finding-the-specific-version-of-pythons-math-and-cmath-modules)

Comment: You can use python version instead of those library version

Comment: @leaves: I just found out win32com is not in-built library with Python. So how can I find its version? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the version of these modules in the  `Python3.x/Lib/__pycache__` folder.
As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=modules%20versions#compiled-python-files) the version is available in this format *module.version.pyc*

Example: *datetime.cpython-39.pyc* means version 3.9

In fact, the version of the built-in modules is the same as the version of python.

Comment: I just found out win32com is not in-built library with Python. So how can I find its version? Thanks!

Comment: In the cmd ```pip list``` and find _pywin32    301_. **301** is the version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But why is pywin32 version the same as win32com?

Comment: Because it is part of pywin32. As you can see in the GitHub repo of [pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/tree/master/com/win32com)