# AttributeError: module 'keras' has no attribute 'initializers'

Tags: initialization, neural-network, keras

I am trying to introduce keras.initializers into my net,  [following this link](https://keras.io/initializers/):

```
import keras
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop, Adam
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, LSTM, Dense, merge, Activation
from keras.models import Model, Sequential

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, init='lecun_uniform', input_shape=(6,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(27, init='lecun_uniform'))
model.add(Activation('linear'))

rms = RMSprop(lr = 0.01)
keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=-0.05, maxval=0.05, seed=None)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=rms)
```

And it fails with the following error:

```
keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=-0.05, maxval=0.05, seed=None)

AttributeError: module 'keras' has no attribute 'initializers'
```

Any ideas as to why it happens?

Comment: Try either `import keras.initializers` or `from keras.initializers import RandomUniform`.

Comment: Which version of keras are you using?

Comment: When I do `import keras.initializers` I get `ImportError: No module named 'keras.initializers'` error.

Comment: How do I figure out my version of keras if `python -c "import keras; print keras.__version__"` doesn't work?

Comment: Any luck? I'm also stuck with this...!

Comment: No good solution yet, I am afraid. I semi-solved the problem of weight initialisation with `model.get_weights()` and `model.set_weights()` but it's not a proper solution unfortunately.

Comment: If keras.__version__ doesn't work, check out waterproof's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180543/how-to-check-version-of-python-modules

Change their line:
`if pkg.key in ['setuptools', 'statlib', 'construct']`
To 
`if pkg.key in ['keras']`

Answer (score 3):

You have to check version of Keras being used. Probable mistake is that you have 1.x.x and trying to use initializers from Keras 2.x.x