# How to check what version of Virtual Env is installed

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I wanted to know what version of virtual env is installed ? My OS is windows 10

Thank you

Comment: Use this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180543/how-to-check-version-of-python-modules

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your terminal use the command:
`virtualenv --version`

Example output:
`15.1.0`

Answer (score 5):

If you mean the module that is used in python you can check them with `pip freeze` or `pip3 freeze` based on the package manager you use.

So it would be like below:

```sh
pip freeze | grep virtualenv
```

output:

```sh
virtualenv==16.0.0
```

Comment: I am using Windows CMD. The grep command is not recognized, I used pip freeze and it also showed me all the version and installed packages so +1.

Comment: @Adds for Windows use `findstr` instead, as `pip freeze | findstr virtualenv`. The `grep` or commonly Global Regular Expression Print is used as regex parser command-line utility for searching plain-text data sets for lines in UNIX based OS. `findstr` does the same.

Answer (score 1):

```py
C:\Users\donhu\temp2023_01_08>python -m virtualenv --version
virtualenv 20.17.1 from C:\Users\donhu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\virtualenv\__init__.py
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows and Conda environment. You can use this command to see Virtual Environments:

```
conda info --envs
```