# TypeError: ttest_1samp() got an unexpected keyword argument 'alternative'

Tags: python, scipy

I keep getting this error message:

```
TypeError: ttest_1samp() got an unexpected keyword argument 'alternative'
```

My code is:

```
test_stat, p_value = ttest_1samp(FF['Time'], popmean=40, alternative='greater')
print('the p-value is', p_value)
```

Comment: What `scipy` version are you using?

Comment: It was an older one.  I updated and got it fixed.  Its all new to me.  What code do you use to check the versions?  This I still do not know.  Thanks.

Comment: You can get the list of installed packages with their versions using `pip freeze`. For the version of a specific library: `import {library_name}, print({library_name}.__version__)`. You may also check here for different responses depending on your OS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180543/how-to-check-version-of-python-modules

Answer (score 4):

Updating scipy version should help:

```
pip install --upgrade scipy
```