# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str in the bitvavo api

Tags: python, list, api, typeerror

```
    from python_bitvavo_api.bitvavo import Bitvavo

bitvavo = Bitvavo()
response = bitvavo.candles('BTC-EUR', '1h', {})
for candle in response['candles']:
    print('Timestamp', candle[0], ' open', candle[1], ' high', candle[2], ' low', candle[3], ' close', candle[4], ' volume', candle[5])
```

Copied this code straight form here: [https://docs.bitvavo.com/#tag/Market-Data/paths/~1{market}~1candles/get](https://docs.bitvavo.com/#tag/Market-Data/paths/%7E1%7Bmarket%7D%7E1candles/get)

Upon running, it provides this error to me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\indig\Documents\Python Projects\historical_data.py", line 5, in <module>
    for candle in response['candles']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Any help please

Comment: Weird...the documentation literally has that block of code there. Either the documentation is out of date, or you have an old/different version than is in the documentation. Can you verify what the latest version is, and that you're on that version? Clearly, `response` is supposed to be a `dict` according to the documentation, but it's a `list` instead. What's actually in that list, I wonder?

Comment: If I input     for candle in response[0]:    for example, I get the following error:  TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Bitvavo API (2.2.0) is the version of the documentation and my python version is 3.7

Comment: Well then `response[0]` is an integer and not a list; I'm asking what's in the whole list of `response`.

Comment: The list contains timestamps, open, highs, lows, closes and volumes of a currency. However I dont know anything besides that.

Comment: How did you get the API? Have you verified that your version is 2.2.0? When I look on [GitHub](https://github.com/bitvavo/python-bitvavo-api/tags), that project hasn't been updated since like 2020, and the latest version is `v1.2.0`. So, you'll have to make sure you're downloading the API through the official channel, since it seems like unless they use a different versioning scheme for their API, you just have an old version.

Comment: I went to docs.bitvavo.com and just copied the code which they presented there, I have used this code before in a project, however this is the first time for me using this particular module inside the API. I'll have a look at the GitHub page you mentioned.

Comment: I'm not asking where you got the *code*, I'm asking where you got the _**API itself**_. As in, the module/library that is installed on your machine that you are interfacing with. Where did you get it and/or how did you install it? And you didn't answer my question about which version of the API is installed on your system.

Comment: Oh sorry, what do you mean with where I got the API itself? And how can I view the version number?

Comment: I mean, you're able to do `from python_bitvavo_api.bitvavo import Bitvavo` - so, what did you have to do to be able to import the `python_bitvavo_api` module? If you didn't install it, then you'd get an error. As far as getting the version, just google questions like that. I don't have unlimited time to explain things that can be found with a quick google search. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180543/how-to-check-the-version-of-python-modules) for info on how. I found that with a quick google search.

Comment: The python-bivavo-api version I am using is 1.2.2 and I got it through pip install python-bitvavo-api

Comment: Yup so that's clearly way too old of a version, so you'll have to go to their official site and figure out how you can get the latest version.

Comment: I figured it out, I removed the ['candles'] part from the code and now I get the list I need.

Comment: Well you're going to be coding blind against an API that's for a way newer version, so to me that doesn't solve the issue, it just sidesteps it while still leaving you in a tough spot.

Comment: But this https://pypi.org/project/python-bitvavo-api/1.2.2/#history does say that its the most recent version from Apr 16, 2021

Comment: Well sounds like they have a really confusing setup...the API version should match the version of the package, otherwise that makes no sense. Nothing we can really do about that, I guess, other than contacting them maybe. But it just feels weird that your API doesn't match what the documentation says - it really seems like there's a newer API that they don't have a link to on that page.