# Getting package version using pkg_resources?

Tags: python, pkg-resources

What is the recommended way getting hold of the package version of a package in the `$PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path`?

I remember that the `pkg_resource` module has some functionality for this but I can not find any related information. Please don't point me to solution using a `version.py` file and reading it somehow. Using `pkg_resources` is the way to go but how exactly?

Comment: since Python 3.8, you have [importlib.metadata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html).

Answer (score 29):

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution("PIL").version
'1.1.7'
```

Comment: This gives me an error: `DistributionNotFound: The 'PIL' distribution was not found and is required by the application`

Comment: PIL is just an example package name. You would use the name of whatever package you're trying to check the version of.

Comment: I have PIL installed on the environment, so the command should have worked. Actually, `pkg_resources.get_distribution('Pillow').version` worked for me. Other packages that worked are `numpy`, `scipy`. `os`, `math` did not work.

Answer (score 2):

I found it quite unreliable to use the various tools available (including the best one `pkg_resources` mentioned by [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4939465/7262247)), as most of them do not cover all cases. For example built-in modules and modules not installed but just added to the python path (by your IDE for example). Since we needed a reliable way to get the version of *any* package, module or submodule, I ended up writing [getversion](https://smarie.github.io/python-getversion/). It is quite simple to use:

```
from getversion import get_module_version
import foo
version, details = get_module_version(foo)
```

See the [documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-getversion/) for details.