# checking suds version in python

Tags: python, suds

how to check the version of suds installed in python, i look over in the net but i cannot find one.

i try this one. in running python manage.py shell

```
>>> import suds
>>> suds
```

but i got the python version on running it.

```
<module 'suds' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/__init__.pyc'>
```

how can I check the suds version?

i try also suds version but i got this error

```
>>> import suds
>>> suds version
  File "<console>", line 1
    suds version
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>>> import suds
>>>> print suds.__version__
0.4.1
```

Tada.

**Edit**: [A more generic question was asked about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710609/checking-python-module-version-at-runtime), and [here's a kind-of-hacky script](http://pythonwise.blogspot.com/2009/01/find-module-version.html) that checks for common names for the version constant.

Comment: +1.  To further this, since the place a `version` is stored differs from lib to lib, I always start with `>>> dir(module)`