# Trying to use SUDS with Python 2.7

Tags: python, suds

I have a SUDS program I'm running successfully under 2.5.4 but have convinced myself that I'd like some of the features of 2.7 (like ordered Dictionaries).

The following sample runs nicely under 2.5.4 but fails under 2.7:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Imports
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import sys
import os
# The Suds SOAP library.
from suds.plugin import MessagePlugin

print "This is a test"
```

Under 2.7 I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
  from suds.plugin import MessagePlugin
ImportError: No module named plugin
```

Would anyone care to speculate why this is happening to me?

Comment: what version of suds do you have, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070093/checking-suds-version-in-python/10070121#10070121. Will tell you how to get your version.

Comment: Have you reinstalled the **suds** package with your Python 2.7? The latest **suds** (0.4) is importing without any errors on my Python 2.7.

Comment: SUDS version was the problem.

Isn't it wonderful how SourceForge links to the obsolete version :-)