# What is the pyodbc version?

Tags: python

I can establish whether suds is installed by following these instructions:

[checking suds version in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070093/checking-suds-version-in-python)

i.e. by running the following commands inside the Python console:

```
>>>> import suds
>>>> print suds.__version__
0.4.1
```

I now want to establish if pyodbc is installed.  I have tried this:

```
>>>> import pyodbc
>>>> print pyodbc.__version__
```

The import produces no error.  However, when I attempt to print the version; I see this:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '**version**'

Is there anything else I can try.  PIP does not appear to be installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute name is just `version`:

```py
print(pyodbc.version)
```

Could have found this out using `dir`:

```
import pyodbc

print(dir(pyodbc))
```

outputs

```
[..., 'version']
```

Answer (score 2):

@DeepSpace gives the correct answer above for this package or others that include specific versions.

If you've got other packages which don't have version numbers in the code itself, you can try printing `pyodbc.__file__`. Then navigate to that directory.

Then do an `ls` (or `dir` on Windows).

You should see several files / directories containing `pyodbc`. The name of one of those directories will probably include the version number, e.g. `pyodbc-4.0.34.dist-info` for a relatively recent installation implies version 4.0.34.

You can also read the `METADATA` file (in the `pyodbc-4.0.34.dist-info` directory) and look for the line which explicitly labels the Version, e.g. `Version: 4.0.34`.