# Version number in Django applications

Tags: django

I'm working on a Django application and I want to display the version of the application (such that people, who find bugs know the version of the application and can provide better bug reports).

Is there a universally accepted way to store version number in Django (I mean the version of my application, not Django) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/459185

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems the settings file would be a reasonable location to store the version number. I don't believe there is any Django accepted way to store a version number of your personal application. It seems like an application specific variable that you should define.

For more information on getting the version number out of svn: [Getting SVN revision number into a program automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449935/getting-svn-revision-number-into-a-program-automatically)

Answer (score 31):

I was looking for this exact same question, and found your question. The answer you accepted is not quite satisfactory to me.

I am working with django debugtoolbar, in there you can also show all versions of the apps used. I was wondering how to get the versions of my custom applications to show there as well.

Looking a bit further I found this question and answer:
[How to check the version of a installed application in Django in running time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145483/how-to-check-the-version-of-a-installed-application-in-django-in-running-time?rq=1)

This answer however does not tell me where to put this `__version__`

So I looked in to an open application, which does show up in django toolbar.
I looked in to the django restframework code, there I found out:

the version is put in the `__init__.py` file

(see [https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/**init**.py](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/__init__.py))

and it is put here as:

```
__version__ = '2.2.7'
VERSION = __version__  # synonym
```

And after this, in his setup.py, he gets this version from this `__init__.py` :
see: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/setup.py

like this:

```
import re

def get_version(package):
    """
    Return package version as listed in `__version__` in `init.py`.
    """
    init_py = open(os.path.join(package, '__init__.py')).read()
    return re.match("__version__ = ['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"]", init_py).group(1)

version = get_version('rest_framework')
```

**When using buildout and zestreleaser:**

By the way, I am using buildout and zest.releaser for building and versioning.

In this case, above is a bit different (but basically the same idea):

see http://zestreleaser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/versions.html#using-the-version-number-in-setup-py-and-as-version

The version in setup.py is automatically numbered by setup.py, so in `__init__.py` you do:

```
import pkg_resources

__version__ = pkg_resources.get_distribution("fill in yourpackage name").version
VERSION = __version__  # synonym
```

Comment: Isn't there a better way to `get_version` than to parse your own python code with a regex?

Answer (score 28):

There are many places where you can store your app version number and a few methods that allow you to show it in django templates. A lot depends on the release tool you're using and your own preferences.

Below is the approach I'm using in my current project.

## Put the version number into version.txt

I'm storing the app version number in the *version.txt* file. It's one of the locations the [zest.releaser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zest.releaser) release tool (that I'm using) takes into account while doing a release.

The whole content of *version.txt* is just the app version number, for example: 1.0.1.dev0

## Read the number to a variable in settings.py

```py
...    
with open(version_file_path) as v_file:
    APP_VERSION_NUMBER = v_file.read()
...
```

## Create a custom context processor

*This paragraph and the following ownes are based on the wonderful [answer by bcchun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/433209/878027) to [Can I access constants in settings.py from templates in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/433162/878027)*

A custom context processor will allow you to add the app version number to the context of every rendered template. You won't have to add it manually every time you render a template (and usually you'll want to have the version number somewhere in the footer of every page).

Create *context_processors.py* file in your app directory:

```
from django.conf import settings

def selected_settings(request):
    # return the version value as a dictionary
    # you may add other values here as well
    return {'APP_VERSION_NUMBER': settings.APP_VERSION_NUMBER}
```

## Add the context processor to settings.py

```py
TEMPLATES = [{
    ...
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            ...
            'your_app.context_processors.selected_settings'
        ],
    },
 }]
```

## Use `RequestContext` or `render` in views

[RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext) and `render` populate the context with variables supplied by context_processors you set in *settings.py*.

Example:

```
def some_view(request):
    return render(request, 'content.html')
```

## Use it in a template

```html
...
<div>{% trans 'App version' %}:{{APP_VERSION_NUMBER}}</div>
....
```

Answer (score 12):

For me the best result/approach is to use the `__init__.py` on the project folder, such as

```
.
├── project_name
│   ├── __init__.py
```

and later check using the standar way, as said in ([PEP396](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/))

```
>>> import project_name
>>> project_name.__version__
'1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 10):

I solved this by adding a templatetag to my django project:

in proj/templatetags, added version.py:

```
from django import template
import time
import os

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def version_date():
    return time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime('../.git')))
```

Then, in my base.html (or whichever template), adding:

```
{% load version %}
<span class='version'>Last Updated: {% version_date %}</span>
```

Comment: That's a pretty interesting answer - I like the git plugin.

Comment: Great answer !!

Comment: I think this is the best one because contrary to other solutions, you don´t need to modify your views (which can be cumbersome if you have a lot of them!). Simply change the base template, I love it!

Answer (score 8):

If using GIT for source versioning, you might want manual promotion of stable 
releases, and automatic numbering for development commits.

One why to obtain this in a Django project is:

In "PROJECT/_ *init* _.py" define:

```
__version__ = '1.0.1'
__build__ = ''
```

Then in setting.py do:

```
import os
import subprocess
import PROJECT

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

try:
    PROJECT.__build__ = subprocess.check_output(["git", "describe", "--tags", "--always"], cwd=BASE_DIR).decode('utf-8').strip()
except:
    PROJECT.__build__ = PROJECT.__version__ + " ?"
```

Thus, PROJECT._ *build* _ will show:

```
v1.0.1 in stable releases
```

and

```
v1.0.1-N-g8d2ec45
```

when the most recent tag doesn't point to the last commit (where N counts the number of additional commits after tag, followed by commit signature)

Comment: Elegant, I like this. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I would only add `.strip()` after `.decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: Thank you @Dário .. adding .strip() certainly wouldn't hurt, but in my opinion it wouldn't help either, as the output of "git describe" is predictable, and doesn't contain any trailing spaces.

Comment: In recent projects, I started adding the "--always" option; this helps when no tag has been assigned yet

Comment: Without `strip()` I was getting a trailing newline for some reason, didn't check why though. I'll try the `"--always"` option, sounds reasonable. Thanks.

Comment: mmhhh ... interesting ... strip() added ! Better safe then sorry, thank you @Dário

Comment: I like this answer, but I needed to replace the first abspath with dirname for it to work

Comment: Thank you @deMangler. In my projects, I usually move "down" the default "settings.py" file into a "project/settings" folder (actually, a module).
That's why I then need to adjust the definition for BASE_DIR.
I edited my comment to restore the more common expression as given by the "startproject" command.

Answer (score 2):

Not for Django applications, per se, but for Python modules, yes. See [PEP 396](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/), [PEP 386](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0386/) and the **[verlib](https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distutilsversion)** library (**easy_install verlib**).

(I’d elaborate, but I just now discovered this, myself.)

Answer (score 1):

Version info is typically maintained in git commit tags. Else, even git commits and last updated time is a good indicator of which version is running and when it was deployed.

For those using `django-rest-framework` and only having an API, you can return both of these; "last updated" as well as "last git commit" using an `/api/version` endpoint:

In `views.py`:

```
import os
import time
import subprocess
import json

class VersionViewSet(ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        # ['git', 'describe', '--tags'] # use this for named tags (version etc)
        # ['git', 'describe', '--all', '--long'] # use this for any commit
        # git log -1 --pretty=format:"Last commit %h by %an, %ar ("%s")"
        # {"commit_hash": "%h", "full_commit_hash": "%H", "author_name": "%an", "commit_date": "%aD", "comment": "%s"}
        FILE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        git_command = ['git', 'log', '-1', '--pretty={"commit_hash": "%h", "full_commit_hash": "%H", "author_name": "%an", "commit_date": "%aD", "comment": "%s"}']
        git_identifier = subprocess.check_output(git_command, cwd=FILE_DIR).decode('utf-8').strip()
        git_identifier = json.loads(git_identifier)
        last_updated = time.strftime('%a, %-e %b %Y, %I:%M:%S %p (%Z)', time.localtime(os.path.getmtime('.git'))).strip()
        return Response({
            "last_updated": last_updated,
            "git_commit": git_identifier
        }, status=200)
```

In `urls.py`:

```
from myapp.views import VersionViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
...
router.register(r'version', VersionViewSet, base_name='version')
```

This creates the endpoint in line with the other endpoints in your API.

Output will be seen like this at `http://www.example.com/api/version/`:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "last_updated": "Mon, 6 May 2019, 11:19:58 PM (IST)",
    "git_commit": {
        "commit_hash": "e265270",
        "full_commit_hash": "e265270dda196f4878f4fa194187a3748609dde0",
        "author_name": "Authorname",
        "commit_date": "Mon, 6 May 2019 23:19:51 +0530",
        "comment": "The git commit message or subject or title here"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this option `__import__('project').VERSION` or `__import__('project').__version__`. The version is put in the `__init__.py` file as everybody said, for example:

```
proyect_name
  | __init__.py

# __init__.py file
VERSION = '1.0.0' # or __version__ = '1.0.0'
```

Now from everywhere you can get it:

```
# Error tracking settings
sentry_sdk.init(
    ...
    release=__import__('cjvc_project').VERSION
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a context processor and it looks like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')

from content_services import __version__


def get_app_version(request):
    """
    Get the app version
    :param request:
    :return:
    """
    return {'APP_VERSION': __version__}
```

Since the project name is `content_services` I have to change the sys path up 1 level so I can import it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you use Git and version tagging you can display the application version in admin site header.

Create a `version.py` file in the project or any app module:

```
import os
import subprocess

FILE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


def get_version_from_git():
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(['git', 'describe', '--tags'],
                                       cwd=FILE_DIR).decode('utf-8').strip()
    except:
        return '?'


VERSION = get_version_from_git()
```

Add the version to admin site header in `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

from utils import version

...

admin.site.site_header = mark_safe('MyApp admin <span style="font-size: x-small">'
                                   f'({version.VERSION})</span>')
```

If you need to provide the version to external tools like Django Debug Toolbar, you can expose the version in project `__init__.py` as suggested above:

```
from utils import version

__version__ = version.VERSION
VERSION = __version__  # synonym
```