# Parsing a specific website crashes the Python process

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Looking to parse an HTML page for images (from http://www.z-img.com), and when I load the page into BeautifulSoup (bs4), Python crashes. The "problem details" shows that `etree.pyd` was the "Fault Module Name", which means its probably a parsing error, but so far, I can't quite nail down the cause of it.

Here's the simplest code I can boil it down to, on Python2.7:

```
import requests, bs4

url = r"http://z-img.com/search.php?&ssg=off&size=large&q=test"
r = requests.get(url)
html = r.content
#or 
#import urllib2
#html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup  = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
```

along with a sample output on PasteBin (http://pastebin.com/XYT9g4Lb), after I had passed it through JsBeautifier.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug [that was fixed in `lxml` version 2.3.5](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/commit/901c891b37e9bc54834d0ba2396d33612e08b85f). Upgrade to version 2.3.5 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, there you go, naturally the first thing I try after I submit the question is the solution: the `<!DOCTYPE>` tag seems to be at the root of it. I created a new HTML file, temp.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
</html>
```

and passed that to BeautifulSoup as an HTML string, and that was enough to crash Python again. So I just need to remove that tag before I pass the HTML to BeautifulSoup in the future:

```
import requests, bs4

url = r"http://z-img.com/search.php?&ssg=off&size=large&q=test"
r = requests.get(url)
html = r.content
#or 
#import urllib2
#html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

#replace the declaration with nothing, and my problems are solved
html = html.replace(r"<!DOCTYPE>", "")
soup  = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Hope this saves someone else some time.

Comment: That sounds like a serious bug. Perhaps you should report it.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it was already reported and [fixed in `lxml` version 2.3.5](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/commit/901c891b37e9bc54834d0ba2396d33612e08b85f).

Comment: @icktoofay Thanks for checking, I'm still on 2.3.4 (just found out about `pkg_resources` too, so bonus http://stackoverflow.com/a/4939465/541208)