# Single place to keep `__version__`?

Tags: python, setuptools

I want to keep `__version__` of my package in a single source file that would be accessible to `__init__` and also to be able to import it in `setup` without being dependent on the package's dependencies.

Assume I have a package with a single module `module_a` with version `1.0.0` and have a single dependency - `module_b`.

`module-a/src/module_a/__init__.py`:

```
__version__ = `1.0.0`

from module_a.inner.foo import bar
```

`module-a/src/module_a/inner/foo.py`:

```
from module_b import baz
...
def bar():
   baz.do_something()
```

`module-a/setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup
from module_a import __version__

setup(
    version=__version__,
    ...,
)
```

Now when I want to update `module_a` to version `1.0.1` I only need to update `__init__.py` and not `setup.py`.

The problem is now that `setup` depends on `module-b` being installed, which is not good.

My current workaround:
`module-a/src/module_a.__init__.py`:

```
__version__ = `1.0.0`

try:
    from module_a.foo import bar
except ImportError:
    # this should happen only when import __version__, __name__ from setup.py
    pass
```

Now setup does not depend on `module-b` :)
But the problem is that if for some reason
`from module_a.inner.foo import bar` fails (for instance in case - `module-b` was not installed) the import will fail silently and not raise a proper exception and  `module_a.foo` won't be accessible from `module_a`.

Is there a proper way to fix this ?

Comment: Some argue that you shouldn't have a `__version__` at all since it's outdated are pretty much replaced by standardized distribution metadata. But if you really want to include it, just set it from the distribution metadata: `__version__ = importlib.metadata.version("my-package")`

Comment: Do note that `setup.py` is outdated. You might want to consider upgrading to a more modern build system, or at least use `setuptools` with a `pyproject.toml` file.

Comment: As mentioned already there are better ways to solve this. But first, you don't need `__version__`, instead code should call `importlib.metadata.version()`. -- On the other hand if you really want a `__version__` attrbute: if you use `pyproject.toml` or `setup.cfg` instead of `setup.py`, then there are straightforward ways to get the bersion string from this `__version__` attribute. Example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65625285

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use a technique similar to what [@Farhood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76846216/2988730) suggests in some published packages:

- https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
- https://scikit-guess.readthedocs.io/en/sine/index.html
- ...

There is a separate [`version.py`](https://gitlab.com/madphysicist/haggis/-/blob/master/src/haggis/version.py) which can be independently imported.

The package root level [`__init__`](https://gitlab.com/madphysicist/haggis/-/blob/master/src/haggis/__init__.py) simply does

```
from version import __version__
```

[`setup.py`](https://gitlab.com/madphysicist/haggis/-/blob/master/setup.py) uses import machinery to load version from the same place. The important bits look like this:

```
from importlib.util import spec_from_file_location, module_from_spec

spec = spec_from_file_location('version', join(dirname(__file__) or '.', 'src', 'haggis', 'version.py'))
mod = module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
# use mod.__version__
```