# Selenium doesn't return after starting Chrome but returns after starting Firefox?

Tags: python, google-chrome, firefox, selenium

I am trying to execute the following code in Python with Selenium:

```
def create_browser(first_page=None):
    print "Starting"
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    if first_page:
        browser.get(first_page);
    print "Done."
    return browser

browser = create_browser()
```

When I execute this code, Chromium starts but the "Done" statement doesn't get printed. However, if I replace `Chrome()` by `Firefox()` the browser starts and "Done" gets printed. I tried to verfiy this in terminal too. If I execute following series of statements:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

When I replace `Chrome()` by `Firefox()` the terminal returns normally and displays `>>` (in the python shell but that doesn't happen with Chromium. Can anyone tell what's going wrong here. I really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Update:

I am not sure if this helps but when I execute using `webdriver` a file called `chromedriver.log` gets generated in the directory containing my code. It has the following contents:

```
[0.000][INFO]:      ChromeDriver 20.0.1133.0 /home/therookie/bin/chromedriver
[1.000][FINE]:      Initializing session with capabilities {
   "browserName": "chrome",
   "chromeOptions": {
      "args": [  ],
      "extensions": [  ]
   },
   "javascriptEnabled": true,
   "platform": "ANY",
   "version": ""
}

[1.001][INFO]:      Launching chrome: /usr/bin/google-chrome --disable-hang-monitor --disable-prompt-on-repost --dom-automation --full-memory-crash-report --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --ignore-certificate-errors --homepage=about:blank
[11.796][SEVERE]:   Failed to initialize connection
```

Comment: What version of selenium and chrome driver?

Comment: I am not really sure. How do I check?

Comment: Way to check a python library - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710609/checking-python-module-version-at-runtime/4939465#4939465 and what is the chrome driver version is the one you installed (check the executable file name)

Comment: I downloaded it from https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/detail?name=chromedriver_linux64_20.0.1133.0.zip&can=4&q

Comment: And I guess that's deprecated and that's the reason I'm having this problem. :(

Comment: Ok. I downloaded ChromeDriverversion 2.9 and copied it to /usr/bin and ensured that it has `-rwx------` permission, still I have the same problem. @Amey - Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using the selenium v2.39 ?

Comment: Yup. Its selenium 2.39

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome requires a special file called chromedriver to run. Look [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) to see what chromedriver is

`from selenium import webdriver
    import os
    chromedriver = "PATH_TO_CHROMEDRIVER"
    os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver)`

This should launch Chrome and print done.

Comment: Actually, if chromedriver is installed anywhere in your path (e.g. you may have installed it via, brew install chromedriver) then webdriver.Chrome() will find it. This is good to know if you have multiple versions of chromedriver in your path, somewhow.