# Require a minimum version of a python module

Tags: python

I need to ensure that one of the imported packages is at least v1.2.6. All the questions I have seen on here check the version of Python running. I would like to check the version of the module.

My current solution is messy. There must be a pythonic solution to this.

```py
import pypfopt
ver = pypfopt.__version__

major, minor, iter = ver.split('.')

major = int(major)
minor = int(minor)
iter  = int(iter)

if major < 1:
    logger.error("major version less than 1")

if minor < 2:
    logger.error("minor version less than 2")

if iter < 6:
    logger.error("iter version less than 6")
```

#### Possible duplicate:

While there are similar questions on SO, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180543/how-to-check-version-of-python-modules), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710609/checking-a-python-module-version-at-runtime), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180543/how-to-check-version-of-python-modules), these are addressing how to get and print the result from `module.__version__`, which I am already doing.

My question, is whether there is a clean, pythonic way to check that version number against the minimum version number. eg:

```py
if pypfopt.__version__ < 1.2.6:
    logger.error("Version is too low. Update")
```

but `__version__` returns a string, and since there are two decimals (1.2.6) it can't be converted to a float, and then compared. Currently, I am converting each individual number to an int, and then doing comparisons.

- There's no way a solution this messy is the right way to do it.
- I'm using 10 lines to compare two numbers.

Comment: I believe this kind of thing would usually be dealt with at install-time. How are you distributing the module?

Comment: Normally I would. We had an older version running on most of our machines, and I want to make sure that before any of them start running the script, they've updated to the latest version since we need a bug fix that came out with 1.2.6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check version of python modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180543/how-to-check-version-of-python-modules)

Comment: @AMC, Not quite. I am able to get a string of the version "1.2.6" but converting each part to an int, and then checking it against the minimum version seems convoluted. Seems like there is probably a pythonic way that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887762/how-do-i-compare-version-numbers-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `packaging` module. Install it with `pip install packaging` and then:

```py
from packaging import version

import pypfopt


ver = pypfopt.__version__

if version.parse(ver) < version.parse('1.2.6'):
    logger.error('Version is too low. Update')
```

Answer (score 2):

`pkg_resources`, distributed with `setuptools`, does what you need and handles situations where `package.__version__` doesn't exist.

Here is how you'd require a minimal version of `pypfopt==1.2.6` in your example:

```
python -c 'import pkg_resources; pkg_resources.require("pypfopt>=1.2.6")'
```

I don't have this package installed so I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 884, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 770, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pypfopt>=1.2.6' distribution was not found
 and is required by the application
```

caveat: I used it a lot until now that I have encountered a problem where the package in question has the right version, but its dependencies are not met, and so `pkg_resources` reports a failure.

For example: I have `pytorch_lightning==1.0.5`installed, but I installed a new version for one of its dependencies that it doesn't list as supported. I was expecting the following to pass, but it fails:

```
python -c 'import pkg_resources; pkg_resources.require("pytorch_lightning>=1.0.4")'
```

with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 884, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 775, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: 
(torch 1.8.0.dev20201106+cu110 (python3.8/site-packages), 
Requirement.parse('torch<1.8,>=1.3'), {'pytorch-lightning'})
```

which is the right thing to do if you want to ensure that not only the desired module is there and has the correct version, but that its dependencies are correct too.

So I'm signalling here, that `pkg_resources` does more than comparing the version number of the installed package - it also checks its dependencies. Which may or may not meet your needs.

---

And here is the version that doesn't check whether the dependencies are OK. In it we use `pkg_resources` to just get the package's version, and delegate the comparison to `packaging` as described in various answers on SO:

```
import pkg_resources
from packaging import version
pkg = "pytorch_lightning"
min_ver = "1.0.4"
got_ver = pkg_resources.get_distribution("pytorch_lightning").version
if version.parse(got_ver) < version.parse(min_ver):
    raise pkg_resources.VersionConflict(f"{pkg}>={min_ver} is needed, but found {pkg}=={got_ver}")
```

This time despite the dependencies being incorrect (in my example), it's sufficient that the version number is high enough, so the script can go ahead and use `pytorch_lightning` (I validated that it works just fine with newer versions of its dependencies).