word2vec not working using gensim library
I am trying to vectorise my dataset using word2vec model provided by gensim. I am facing the error raised by scipy.
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')

# Sample sentences
sentences = [
    "This is a sample sentence.",
    "Word embeddings are cool.",
    "I love natural language processing."
]

# Tokenize the sentences
tokenized_sentences = [word_tokenize(sentence.lower()) for sentence in sentences]

# Train the Word2Vec model
model = Word2Vec(sentences=tokenized_sentences, vector_size=100, window=5, min_count=1, workers=4)

# Get the vector representation of a word
word_vector = model.wv['sample']
print("Vector representation of 'sample':", word_vector)

# Get the most similar words to a given word
similar_words = model.wv.most_similar('sample')
print("Words most similar to 'sample':", similar_words)

This is the code. I want to apply word2vec vectorisation on it.
I am facing the error-
ImportError: cannot import name 'triu' from 'scipy.linalg.special_matrices' (C:\Users\onkar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\special_matrices.py)
I have tried using the older versions (1.10 & 1.12) as well as the latest versions of scipy. Please help me find out the way to resolve this error or please suggest an alternative method.

If the fix in ImportError: cannot import name 'triu' from 'scipy.linalg' - Gensim hasn't worked for you, you may not be effectively rolling back the scipy version in the actually-active Python environment for your code.
Have you confirmed that the desired older scipy is the active version, for example by checking both:

pip freeze from the outer shell environment in which you launch python, to list installed package versions

the true scipy version active for your code at its runtime, using code alongside your Gensim-using code, with a technique suggested at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54869712/130288


import scipy
from importlib_metadata import version
print(version('scipy'))

If these two checks differ, your pip install ... attempting to change the scipy version changed a different available python environment than the one your Gensim code is later running inside.
